# modpost has source but didn't compile

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, yocto

I am building a module in yocto environment.

In local.conf of yocto, I have:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " kernel-modules kernel-devsrc kernel-dev"
```

When compiling the module, I see:

```
root@genericx86-64:/home/srmt-1.5.0/srmt-lkm# make
make -C /lib/modules/5.4.20-yocto-standard/build M=/home/srmt-1.5.0/srmt-lkm modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/lib/modules/5.4.20-yocto-standard/build'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 0 modules
/bin/sh: scripts/mod/modpost: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modpost:94: __modpost] Error 127
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1609: modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/lib/modules/5.4.20-yocto-standard/build'
make: *** [Makefile:39: all] Error 2
```

I checked the folder, it has the source files but didn't compile.

```
root@genericx86-64:/usr/src/kernel/scripts/mod# ls -l
total 156
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   826 Mar  9  2018 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6645 Mar  9  2018 devicetable-offsets.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    54 Mar  9  2018 empty.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 43216 Mar  9  2018 file2alias.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1269 Mar  9  2018 mk_elfconfig.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 71683 Mar  9  2018 modpost.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5228 Mar  9  2018 modpost.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11691 Mar  9  2018 sumversion.c
```

Comment: which version of release are you on

Comment: I am using latest yocto, just git it. The default kernel is 5.4.20-yocto-standard

Comment: can you add `inherit module-base` in your recipe ?